# Call different class after finding instanceof in arraylist

Tags: java

I don't think my title explains it well but I need to call a different class' method after finding that object in an arraylist.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ArrayList.size(); i++) {
      if (ArrayList.get(i) instanceof object) {
        ArrayList.get(i).addInterest();
      }
    }
```

This is what I assumed would work but obviously if I am in a different class (object1), I can't call it. The idea is though that I loop through the arraylist, find those other objects, then call a method from that class to them.

Comment: You need to cast the object like this `((MoneyMarketAccount)accounts.get(i)).myMoneymarketAcctMethod()`

Comment: @onkarruikar That did it. Thank you so much!

Comment: This seems like a liskov's substitution principle violation. Add interest should be an interface implemented by w.e. classes add interest, and use that as your type instead of BankAccount. Then you'd have no need to cast, or even check instanceof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting this in the answer, so the question can be closed.

You need to cast the object like this `((MoneyMarketAccount)accounts.get(i)).myMoneymarketAcctMethod()`

Answer (score 4):

With Java 16 I would write this code like this:

```
for (var account : accounts) {
    if (account instanceof MoneyMarketAccount mma) {
        mma.addInterest();
    }
}
```

It uses the following Java features:

- Enhanced for loop (Introduced in Java 5)
- [Local-Variable Type Inference](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) (Introduced in Java 10)
- [Pattern matching for `instanceof`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394) (Introduced in Java 16)